# What metaphor or phrase can describe an object that is aesthetically pleasing yet totally useless?

Tags: phrase-requests, vocabulary, metaphors

Is there a conventional metaphor or phrase that just hits this meaning:good-looking yet useless?

Comment: "Eye candy" springs to mind. Often though not *always* used to imply uselessness.

Comment: "Eye candy" sounds like viewing a physically attractive person as a sexual object (when used by either sex.) For an actual object, I think "trinket" is the best fit here.

Comment: @steveverrill  I learned the term "eye candy" in terms of computer graphics, UI (e.g., the shiny bits of OS X interface), and ornate set studios.  I learned about the "physically attractive person" interpretation when I used it in describing a film (with stunning buildings) to my parents and got some strange looks in response.  Ever since, I've wondered if there's a specific usage of the term within the tech/internet world that doesn't really touch on the "physically attractive person" meaning.

Comment: The answer may be different depending on whether the object was supposed to be useful or not....

Comment: @steveverrill ... "trinket" implies "small", so it doesn't seem all encompassing enough for the meaning.   A statue can be an ornament, but not a trinket.

Comment: @GreenAsJade I think you could push the definition of trinket as far as anything small enough to be moveable. For an immobile object such as a statue or building, *"folly"* is a good word.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor strange looks from who? Your parents? +1 your comment for being more innocent than your parents.

Comment: @steveverrill Well, who knows about being more innocent, but my point is that the term, in certain circles (computer graphics, user interface, etc.), doesn't seem to have *any* of the connotation of "sexually attractive individual," whereas in other circles, it has almost only that connotation.

Comment: @steveverrill Every definition of "trinket" I can find has the word "small" in it - some definitions are "a small ornament".   Gargolyes are are aesthetically pleasing, tend to serve no purpose (some do) but they are not trinkets or follies.   They are ornaments on a building.

Comment: Interesting, from my own experience it never would have occurred to me that "eye candy" had a sexual aspect. The definition in Collins would suggest that it's a *better* answer than I initially gave it credit for: "eye candy —n
1. a person who is or people considered highly attractive to look at, often implying that they are but lacking in intelligence or depth. 2. something intended to be attractive to the eye without being demanding or contributing anything essential."

Comment: I would call it art. I'm a designer and in graphic design, whether or not it's useful is the difference between being design and art.

Comment: @jt0dd Art per se is of its use.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would simply go with the word *ornament*. Decorative and serving no real purpose otherwise.

Comment: +1 Good point. Improve your answer with more supporting information.

Comment: ...and likewise **decoration**, for much the same meaning.

Comment: I think a difference between "ornament" and "decoration" is that and ornament is most likely to be an object (as requested) wheras a decoration is not necessarily an object.

Comment: -1 from me. It may not assert any usefulness but neither does it imply a lack of it.

Comment: @Rupe If something is described as "purely ornamental" that surely emphasises it has no practical utility?

Answer (score 22):

Consider **ornament**, which principally means:

> *(n) a thing used to make something look more attractive but usually having no practical purpose*

From: *New Oxford American Dictionary*

An object that's aesthetically pleasing and completely useless can be described as **ornamental.**

Answer (score 7):

**Eye candy**: "a slang term for attractiveness"

> (US, idiomatic) Any object or sight with considerable visual appeal. *The computer graphics added lots of eye candy to that movie.*

Answer (score 6):

### Of a person

Bimbo

> Webster's: "an attractive but stupid woman"

Beautiful fool

> *To my knowledge this is a reference to The Great Gatsby meaning a woman who is pretty yet blissfully ignorant. Perhaps it predates that?*

Plastic

> Webster's: "not real or sincere" *[i.e., superficial, malleable]*

Arm candy

> Webster's: "a young attractive person who accompanies a usually older person at
>   social events"

Trophy Wife/Husband

> Slang: a spouse who is valued for superficial reasons.

### Of an object

Bauble

> Webster's: "something of trifling appeal" *[lacking in significance or solid worth, frivolous]*

Trinket

> Webster's: "a piece of jewelry or an ornament that has little value" *[therefore shiny, aesthetically pleasing... not useful]*

Ornament

> Webster's: "something that lends grace or beauty" [*Webster's example sentence reads:* "The columns are there purely as ornament—they have no structural function."]

Tchotchke

> Dictionary.com: Syn for Oranment, Trinket

---

Clearly these aren't all perfect fits as they stand by themselves, but given the proper context they could all be used to convey a sense of useless splendor.

Edit: I removed a couple that would have required more finesse to work into the context.

Comment: What do each of these words mean? Why do you think they might suit the OP's need? What is source of the list?

Comment: The source of this list is my brain. I will edit in definitions.

Comment: I don't think any of the "of an object" list are *necessarily* aesthetically pleasing or decorative except "ornament". Possibly "bauble" too, but in UK English it refers to one very specific type of decoration usually used on Christmas trees.

Comment: I agree @user568458. Added a note to make this concession. We'd need more context to form a proper sentence. I was just getting us close.

Answer (score 3):

Consider *embellishment*, *veneer*, *gloss*, and *window dressing*.

> [window dressing](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/window%20dressing): anything used or done to create a good impression
>
> [gloss](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Gloss), [veneer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/veneer): a superficially attractive appearance
>
> embellishment, also [embellisher](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/embellisher): an ornament

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Knickknack. It is quite close to the word Ornament but it has a more friendly ring to it.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst it might not apply, you may potentially use a phrase such as 'Form over function' I suppose, to indicate that the look of the object outweighs its usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

In vernacular English, "dust collector". Something which just sits there, does nothing, and has to be cleaned semi-regularly to remove the dust which settles upon it. Also implies something of low value:

- When commenting about Aunt Amelia's extensive collection of floppy-eared rabbit `dust collectors` Uncle Wilmer often said philosophically, "Well, they keep her happy - and the durn things didn't cost much...".

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I'm not sure that a "dust collector" has the meaning of "good looking".   Generally, dust-collectors would junk, wouldn't they?

Comment: "Aesthetically pleasing" is in the eye of the beholder. Aunt Amelia might find her collection of floppy-eared bunny statuary (in a variety of amusing and picturesque poses) quite pleasing, aesthetically-wise speaking - but Uncle Wilmer might not.

Comment: Sure - but it is not about whether a particular thing is pleasing to me or you.  The question is whether if you say to me "dust collector" are you communicating "aesthetically pleasing".   If I said that to you, I would not be.   I am questioning your assertion that "dust collector" is a phrase that means "aesthetically pleasing", which is what the question asks for.

Answer (score 1):

Such aesthetically pleasing objects which have no use can usually be found on mantlepieces or knick-knack shelves in kitchens. They may be figurines, small statues, etc. They are known as 'dust-catchers' because that is the only purpose they serve.

Answer (score 1):

[Gold plated turd](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gold%20plated%20turd) - something that is essentially useless but has a layer of gloss to make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

I offer *gimcrack*. As defined by Meriam-Webster [[http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gimcrack]](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gimcrack%5d): a showy object of little use or value.

Also *gewgaw* at the same reference.

Comment: I have to down-vote this answer. The question asks for a "conventional metaphor". Both of these suggestions are quite archaic today, and by no means conventional. Most people would probably not know what you were talking about if you used them, and those who did would probably be chuckling to themselves...

Answer (score 1):

"Fluff" is often used in such manner: "The fancy looking bumper on that car is just **fluff**."

"For show" is also a very common colliquilism that exactly express your idea: "That window display is just **for show**. They don't stock any of those items."

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps you would like, adornment? their very use is purely to be good looking. O
Ornamentation as well. Their very use is defined only as their good looks.