# Word to describe "beautiful but worthless"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a family member who worked at a cat boarding facility. There, she met a couple who jokingly described their cat as "beautiful but worthless." Is there a word in the English language to describe such a purrradox? (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: +1 for the purrradox! The premise reminds me of art. Utterly useless other than to allow those who look upon it to derive whatever pleasure they wish from it. I hope you get a response - I'm interested to know too!

Comment: Priceless = either so expensive or so worthless, that you cannot put a price on it. The cat is priceless - having no worth and yet worths so much in beauty.

Comment: We have a "decorator cat"

Comment: "White elephant" is a term to consider.  Supposedly the term originated from the habit of an Asian prince for gifting people he did not especially like with a white elephant (the real thing).  Since the white elephant was considered sacred the giftee could not simply kill it, but it was very expensive to feed, so the individual was saddled with a continuing burden.

Comment: Related: [What metaphor or phrase can describe an object that is aesthetically pleasing yet totally useless?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173317/what-metaphor-or-phrase-can-describe-an-object-that-is-aesthetically-pleasing-ye) (nouns to these adjectives)

Comment: If one wanted to use a more colloquial term, one could adopt the "bling bling" or "blink" phraseology often used by poets belonging to the Rhythmic Artistic Poetry (RAP) genre. Ofttimes one would use such words in the description of something which is perhaps expensive/beautiful/attractive but also totally useless (not necessarily worthless)... Objects described as "blink" are generally used to show status... kind of like what some individual do with their four-legged friends.

Comment: some might argue that something beautiful has worth by definition.

Comment: 'Superficial' is close as it expresses that the most obvious attribute is really of no relevance.  _superficial beauty_.

Comment: I don't understand the context. How can a cat be "worthless"?

Answer (score 60):

You could say Mrs. Whiskers is ***purely ornamental***.

For example, [Cambridge gives the definition of "ornamental"](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/ornamental) as *precisely* "beautiful rather than useful":

[image: Screenshot of Cambridge Dictionary Online's definition of "ornamental" : "beautiful rather than useful"].

Furthermore, [Vocabulary.com lists "*non-functional*"](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/ornamental) as the first synonym of "*ornamental*", and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornamental_plant#The_term) has this to say about ornamental plants:

> **Ornamental plants** are plants which are grown for display purposes, rather than functional ones.

You could also say Princess Pretty Paws is ***cosmetic***, ***decorative***, or even a mere ***bauble***.  Just don't do it to her face.

Comment: *Tinsel* also figuratively. +1

Comment: @DanBron [*Utilitarian*](https://www.google.com/search?q=utilitarian&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox&channel=sb), but I hardly think that qualifies.  It's far too flamboyant.  Hmmm.... apparently *utilitarian* and *ornamental* are antonyms.

Comment: I'm not sure that ornamental really works: I have, for instance, a number of female acquaintances who are both useful (my vet springs to mind), yet quite ornamental.  Likewise my dogs and horse, and some of my fruit trees: ornamental, but serving useful purposes as well.

Comment: *Purely ornamental* is not a single word. As jamesqf mentions, things can be quite *decorative* (the colloquial definition of *ornamental*), yet entirely functional.

Comment: @jamesqf i would say, then, that your vet is *attractive* (and NOT ornamental).

Comment: Shouldn't that have been *purrly ornamental*?

Comment: @danbron, was my edit not good? What's your opinion?

Comment: @NVZ Personally, I didn't prefer it. The terrible screenshot was intentional from day 1 of this answer, and was part of its (ironic) charm. But, on the other hand, I wasn't going to step on your toes either. But if you want my opinion, I prefer the answer the way it was before you edit.

Comment: @NVZ No problem, though I should have mentioned I appreciated sentiment behind the edit. The screenshot *is* garish, but in this case that just happens to be ironic.

Answer (score 13):

Buried at the end of Dan's answer, without getting a fair shake:

**bauble** -[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=bauble&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> bau·ble /ˈbôbəl/ noun
>
> 1. something that is **superficially attractive but useless or worthless**.

[Caryatids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caryatid) are ornamental. Ornate although they are, they're not baubles; the roof of the Erechtheion requires them for support.

Comment: Per the OP's question, however, I would not refer to a cat as bauble, which I connote as meaning something inanimate and referring generally gems or jewelry.

Answer (score 8):

It's an obscure word: **gewgaw**.

From the *New Oxford American Dictonary*:

a showy thing, especially one that is useless or worthless.

Comment: this is a word for a doodad or trinket, perhaps something you picked up in a tourist gift shop.  i'm not seeing the connection to "beautiful" here.

Comment: I agree with @erich , but it is a lovely word.

Comment: Thanks for all of the comments. It should be noted that other dictionaries define gewgaw as: "A showy trifle; a toy; a splendid plaything; a pretty but worthless bauble." Understandable that we could argue the semantics of pretty vs. beautiful, but gewgaw can refer to something that is aesthetically pleasing to the eye, yet worthless.

Answer (score 5):

The kitty is ***purrty***.

> *pretty:* (often pejorative) Fine-looking; only superficially attractive; initially appealing but having little substance [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pretty)

Comment: purrrrrrrty? (stole joke from @piggy.)

Comment: First I've ever seen *pretty* defined with (often pejorative). +1 for that, i guess

Answer (score 5):

You can say that that particular thing is just "for show".

> **[For show](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/for-show?q=for%20show)**
>
> For the sake of appearance rather than for use (Oxford Dictionaries)

**Example sentence,**

> It was a commonplace of Roman food writing to despise complicated
>   dishes designed for show rather than for taste

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use a single word for this, you might have to settle for an analogy. The problem then becomes the obscurity of the reference, which would then require explanation, thus revealing the economy of words to be illusory. However, here are a couple of examples:

- Paris-Hiltonian
- pyritic

The last has the virtue of actually being in the dictionary.

Comment: It's not cool to make cracks about real live people. Of course, if you are **quoting someone else,** please do indicate that.

Comment: Commenting on public figures seems legit to me. We all knew _exactly_ what he meant.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you're looking for *meretricious*!

> apparently attractive but having in reality no value or integrity.[1]

---

[1] "Meretricious, n.1." OED Online. Oxford University Press, April 2016. Web. 21 April 2016.

Answer (score 2):

Something that's been **[gilded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gild?s=t)** has a thin veneer of pretty gold on top, but underneath that, it may be something worthless. The word is often used metaphorically, as in "[The Gilded Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilded_Age)."

> **Gild**
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to coat with gold, gold leaf, or a gold-colored substance.
> 2. to give a bright, pleasing, or specious aspect to.
>
> (Dictionary.com)

Comment: Gold is more impressive or dazzling than beautiful, I would say. I don't think calling something gilded implies it's beautiful.

Answer (score 2):

***eye candy***

> *Slang.* someone or something that is visually attractive or pleasing but is usually considered to lack worth or merit.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/eye--candy)

***trumpery***

> A showy thing of no intrinsic value; something intended to deceive by false show; worthless finery.
>
> [Fine Dictionary](http://www.finedictionary.com/trumpery.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use *folly* perhaps in a more specific sense:

4. A structure, such as a pavilion in a garden, that is chiefly decorative rather than practical in purpose.

[Source](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/folly)

Comment: Can you use that in a sentence please?

Comment: 18th century English gardens often feature beautiful and elaborate follies.

Comment: Hmpph... Can you use that as the subject in a sentence without 'beautiful' or a similar adjective? :-)

Comment: I'd struggle to be honest, in this case folly refers to a specific type of architectural feature. Follies were structures that had no practical value but were built purely for their aesthetic features. For a similar use that omits 'beuatiful' you could refer to [this](http://zaha-hadid-design.com/shop/the-complete-zaha-hadid) article, specifically _This comprehensive volume covers over two hundred projects – from the earliest experimentations to product design, from **follies** to large-scale built works_

Comment: Well, I guess you earned your +1 (grumble).

Answer (score -1):

If you mean something that you couldn't sell for much money but is nevertheless worth a lot to you, I'd say it had *purely sentimental* value.

Comment: No cat is ever truly worthless. The question is how one defines "worth".  I set the bar low. My cat has a perfect record of keeping the pterodactyls away.

Comment: @Jez Of course you meant **purrrly** sentimental...

Comment: if the value is purely sentimental, then there's no aesthetic value.