# Word for inexpensive tat you can buy from shops

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember reading a very nice word the small trinkets and other tat you can pick up from small shops (like a dollar store). I just cannot remember the word. Can anyone help! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Can you be more specific? What's wrong with *trinkets* (or *tat*)? How will the word be used? Have you tried looking up *trinket* in a thesaurus?

Comment: Thank you. I'm just trying to remember the word, it was a nice sounding one. Yes I checked the thesaurus but didn't find it.

Comment: Baubel, Knick-Knack, Curio, Gewgaw.

Comment: ...bric-a-brac, ornament, dust collector...

Comment: Anything that ashens reviews, aka "Poundland trinkets"

Comment: @user144613  "bibelot?" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bibelot

Comment: gadget, gizmo ?

Comment: @user144613 "breloque?" http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/breloque

Comment: What is 'tat'? That's a new one to me.

Comment: I wonder what the etymology of "tat" is - abbreviation of "tacky shit"?

Comment: @JoeDark, just to mention a typo, it should be 'bauble'.

Comment: Related: [“beautiful but worthless”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244840/word-to-describe-beautiful-but-worthless/244865#244865)

Comment: I'm not sure I'd want to get a tat from a Dollar Store (if I ever were to get one at all).

Comment: I think I was thinking of mass produced junk items... I don't need to use the word, I just don't like not remembering it!

Comment: @Mitch - Yeah.  So far as I know, "tat", here in the US, is short for "tattoo".

Comment: @HotLicks that's the only one I know. Presumably some people in the UK it is something like 'stuff'. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: From personal experience, *tat* is often used as a derogatory singular or collective term to describe new or, more likely, used items which are for sale. The quality or condition of the items is very low and regret often follows soon after the purchase. I've heard this used mainly around the South East area of England. To accentuate how bad the item is, tat is often preceded by *cheap*. I have heard, and used the word *tut*, pronounced *toot*, interchangeably with tat, although tut is usually worse than cheap tat.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps *[tchotchke](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tchotchke)*

> *Informal; North American*: A small object that is decorative rather than strictly functional; a trinket.

*Oxford Dictionary Online*

Migrated from Yiddish, but fairly understood in urban areas of the US.

Comment: This could benefit from a pronunciation and [this list](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8101907#8101907) of synonyms.

Comment: I'm sure that's right in the US. However it wouldn't be understood in most other English-speaking countries. I've never heard it in Britaion and wouldn't know how to say it.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK It's often pronounced *chach-kee*. Purists would want a *t* sound before the initial *ch*. And I'm sure there are some circles in the larger British cities that might recognize the term, although it might not be considered to have migrated to English.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps mathoms? (I am currently reading Lord of the Rings which is why this popped into my mind).

To quote from the LoTR wiki: http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Mathom

> Mathom was the hobbit term for anything which they had no use for but were unwilling to throw away.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a **bagatelle** that is an article or thing of very little value; a trifle.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of **gewgaws**. "A showy thing, especially one that is useless or worthless."

Or **bauble** might be what you're thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly remembered the word!!  It's schlock. Not exactly trinkets but definitely tat. Thank you for some wonderful answers/comments.