# A word or phrase that can be used to describe what is only good-looking but has almost no practical value.?

Tags: single-word-requests

Any word or phrase that can be used to describe someone or something that is only good-looking but has almost no practical value?

> Peter's massively bulking muscles do him a big help in chasing girls,
>   but they are actually ____ when he has to confront a real fighter like
>   Mike Tyson.

Comment: In your example, *useless* is the word I would choose.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244840/word-to-describe-beautiful-but-worthless